# DB2 Update one table from another table

Tags: java, jdbc, db2

I have one table say **"table1"** which is having huge data say **400K records**, i am having another table **"table2"** which is also having huge data say **6000K**. Both tables have almost same columns say "col1" "col2" "col3".

In my application one batch gets run and it update 400K records of "table1" now i need to update **"table2"** for these 400K records. I need to update **"table2"** in chunk so that "table2" doesn't get hanged while updating.

Both table is having row level lock.

Please let me know what is the best way to do this.

Comment: What is the question? How to update in chunk? or How to identify the 400k records in table2?

Answer (score 0):

Each time DB2 performs a modification on a row, the RDBS put two locks:

- One Intent eXclusive at the table
- Update or eXclusive locks at the row.

It is not possible to modify rows without previously putting a lock on the row.

You can reduce the quantity of locks by locking the table, but that reduces the concurrency.

```
alter table xxx locksize table
```

Also, when there are a lot of row locks on a table, they are "escalated" and a same type lock is put at the table.

So, you are getting Row locks but that is normal.

For more information about isolation, you can check this tutorial at DeveloperWorks: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/tutorials/db2-cert6106/index.html?ca=dat